# how to write.table the results of aggregate() when a column of strings is present?

Tags: r

I am doing an analysis that is involved in both numbers and strings. A reproducible example would be:

```
a= c(3,1:4)
c= cbind(a, LETTERS[1:5])
(b=aggregate (c, by= list (c[,1]), F = 'list')  )
```

my problem is that I want to write the output. But obviously

```
write.table(b)
```

doesn't work. Is there a way that I can paste() strings to form one string so to preserve the data.frame structure?

```
(b=aggregate (c, by= list (c[,1]), F = 'paste')  ) # or cat()
```

doesn't work. I think there should be a rather simple workout for this.

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output file to look like?

Comment: A rectangular table.Some cells are composed of delimited text. in  the example above, in the 3rd row: 3 inthe 1st  cell,  3 in the second,  3,3 in the third and 1,4 in the fourth cell

Comment: And how exactly should the rectangular table look? Do you want some different delimited used between columns? Do you need to be able to read it back in to R? Does it have to be text?

Comment: it should look like a data.frame. Some columns, however contain concatenated strings.  I think the delimiter between columns has to be different from that within cells, otherwise there would be no "table". It would be better if I can read it back to R, although parsing seems necessary in this case.